# Nginx vhost redirection being cached?

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, dns

One of our clients commented that the subdomains on their site were redirecting to ours (it's the default domain on the Plesk server). However, even after I added the subdomains to redirect properly (we had a different naming scheme originally), and a wildcard subdomain on top of all that, they're still having the issue.

Any of the subdomains they tried yesterday before the fix are still redirecting the way they were, while any new ones they try work fine. I can't recreate the problem on my end though.

Is their DNS somehow caching the vhost redirection? How is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ask them to try to clear the browser cache, or try a different browser, I know this issue happens on Firefox, it caches the DNS and doesn't try to contact the DNS server again.

Comment: DNS caching makes sense, but I thought that only applied to, you know, IP address stuff. I didn't think it could cache and instruct the server which vhost to serve.

Comment: well at least for firefox, I know as a fact that it caches 301 redirects, and when it gets the first URL again it automatically redirects without checking if the redirect still exists or not.